# Two .docx file mixing into another

Tags: php, xml, docx

My job is to mix two .docx file to another with php.
What is currently working:

- mix the content fine
- font color work fine
- headlines copy good
- text highlighting copy work
- tabulators perfect work

but the list formating not work.

I mix the style.xml, docuemnt.xml, numbering.xml files and save as .zip and rename it to .docx.

What did I leave out?

Comment: _What did I leave out?..._ The relavant part of the code that is causing issues

Comment: Try using an existing package like [krustnic/DocxMerge](https://github.com/krustnic/DocxMerge)?

Comment: I try it but dosent work for me.